# Is it pythonic to use a shallow copy to update an object's attribute?

Tags: python, oop

I found this code in the wild (simplified here), and I was wondering whether this is considered a good practice or not, that is, making a shallow copy (of an object's attribute in this case) for the sole purpose of updating the attribute (and reduce verbosity?). I ask because it is not the first time I see this kind of pattern and it bothers me a bit.

```
class DrawingBoard:
    def __init__(self):
        self.raw_points = []

    def add_point(self, x, y):
        Point = collections.namedtuple('Point', ['x', 'y'])
        points = self.raw_points
        points.append(Point(x, y))
        if len(points) > ......:
           # DO SOMETHING
```

```
board = DrawingBoard()
for x in np.arange(0, 10, 0.1):
    board.add_point(x, np.sin(x))
```

For context, the actual class is performing some action when a certain amount of points have been added. On my first read, I miss this update was happening (**the code is a fair bit more complex**).

My question is: Is it just me not used to this pattern, and this is a mere question of less verbosity vs clarity? or is there something else I am missing? I can see that if we were updating multiple attributes, it could get quite verbose, but I find calling `self.raw_points.append(Points(x,y))` instead of `points.append(Points(x,y))`so much clearer.

Comment: `Point = collections.namedtuple('Point', ['x', 'y'])` should not happen inside the function, btw, because now a class is created for every instance...

Comment: Good point, I simplified the code, but forgot to delete/modify that part which is obviously bad practice yes!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no [copy](https://docs.python.org/3/library/copy.html) of any kind, shallow or otherwise, made in your example.

`points = self.raw_points` means `points` *is* `self.raw_points`. It makes the name `points` an additional reference to the same object that `self.raw_points` refers to, so that:

```
points.append(Points(x,y))
```

is functionally equivalent to:

```
self.raw_points.append(Points(x,y))
```

without the overhead of an additional attribute lookup in `self.raw_points`, which is why this is generally considered a good practice if `self.raw_points` is to be referenced repeatedly.

Comment: Oh, that was obviously a loophole in my understanding (of referencing vs copying). The bit that I suspected I was also missing was the lookup overhead you are mentioning. That makes sense!

Many thanks for the answer!!